# When calling service, onCreate is run but not onStartCommand()

Tags: android, service

I'm working on the code to call a service when android finishes boot-up.

The service is defined in the manifest.xml called myService.

In the class myService, the code override two methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){

    myInit();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");

}


public int onStartCommand(){

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand first line");

    startScheduler();

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");

    //This service is running in the background all the time. Therefore, return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

While running, the logcat can see "onCreate" but never "onStartCommand". I read through the developer website but can't figure out why.

Comments and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Add `super.onCreate()` to your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Hello CommonWare, Is super.onCreate() mandatory in my own onCreate()?

Comment: It is mandatory for activities. I do not know if it is mandatory for services, but I would recommend calling it unless you have a clear reason not to.

Comment: Thanks. Add it. App runs fine with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onStartCommand` [takes an Intent and two integer parameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)).

Try replacing your method with:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand first line");

    startScheduler();

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");

    //This service is running in the background all the time. Therefore, return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

---

As a general rule, if you think you're overriding or implementing a method, always annotate it with `@Override`. That will make the compiler error if you miss a parameter, get the name wrong, etc.